# Removing some characters in a bracket using regex

Tags: regex

I have the following pattern repeating multiple times in my *.csv* file:

`\"validForCountries\":\"[\"BE\", \"DE\", \"XX\"]\"`

I would like to replace it with

`\"validForCountries\":\"[BE, DE, XX]\"`

meaning that I would like to remove all the `\"` occurences **within** the square brackets/array. The number of items in the array may differ. I tried grouping, but I was only getting a match on one of the items within an array. My approach so far: `\\"\[(([A-Z]*)[,\s\\"]*)*?\]\\"`.

I am using VSCode replace tool so I would only need a replace regex expression.

Comment: Are you replacing in a single file, or in multiple files?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew A single file.

Comment: Then it is easy, use `(?<=\\":\\"\[[^\]\[]*)\\"` (does not check for the `]` on the right) or `(?<=\\":\\"\[[^\]\[]*)\\"(?=[^\]\[]*])` (checks for the `]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search and replace in a single file, you can use

```
(?<=\\":\\"\[[^\]\[]*)\\"(?=[^\]\[]*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QmanQj/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\\":\\"\[[^\]\[]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `\":\"[` and then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\\"` - a `\"` substring
- `(?=[^\]\[]*])`  -  a positive lookahead that makes sure there are zero or more chars other than `]` and `[` and then a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.